# Tensorflow Retrain on Windows

Tags: python, windows, machine-learning, tensorflow

When I follow the tutorials of "[How to Retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/)", I need to build the retainer like this

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
```

However, my tensorflow on windows does not have such directory. I am wondering why and how can I solve the problem?
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the screenshot, it appears that you have installed the TensorFlow PIP package, whereas the instructions in the [image retraining tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/) assume that you have cloned the [Git repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) (and can use `bazel` to build TensorFlow).

However, fortunately the script (`retrain.py`) for image retraining is a simple Python script, which you can download and run without building anything. Simply download the copy of `retrain.py` from the branch of the TensorFlow repository that matches your installed package (e.g. if you've installed TensorFlow 0.12, you can download [this version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)), and you should be able to run it by typing `python retrain.py` at the Command Prompt.

Comment: how can you run the label_image in windows once the model is trained? label_image has no python version on the repository https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12/tensorflow/examples/label_image.

Answer (score 6):

In my case tensorflow version is 1.2 and corresponding retrain.py is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining). 
[image]
Download and extract flowers images from [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz). 
Now run the the retrain.py file as

`python retrain.py --image_dir=path\to\dir\where\flowers\images\where\extracted --output_lables=retrained_labels.txt --output_graph=retrained_graph.pb`

note: the last two arguments in the above command are optional.

**Now to test the retrained model:**

- go the [master branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining) and download the label_image.py code as shown below
- [image]
- Then run `python label_image.py --image=image/path/to/test/classfication --graph=retrained_graph.pb --labels=retrained_labels.txt`
- The result will be like [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on windows. My windows could not find `script.retrain`. I downloaded `retrain.py` file from tensoflow website at [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py). Then, copied the file in the tensorflow folder and run the retrain script using Python command.

Comment: Where can I find the Tensorflow folder in my system