# How to retrain image on Windows

Tags: python, windows, docker, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm a freshman, and have just started my trip toward machine learning. I followed a book and the video tutorial of Josh Gordon (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSKfRcEDGUs), but was stopped at "TensorFlow for poets", in which says:

```
# In Docker
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos
```

And I got 2 problems here:

1. there's no such directory called 'image_retraining' nor file called retrain.py;
2. the docker can't be opened.

The first problem seems easy to solve as I found the [Tensorflow Retrain on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433282/tensorflow-retrain-on-windows),
but the second one remain unsolved. Every time I start the "Boot2DockerStart", it will flash an error saying 'error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1' and then quit. So I searched, most answers are saying that the Virtualization is disabled, but I checked that though the Task Manager, On which the Virtualization Status is 'Enable', which really confused me...
So I wonder: How to fix the docker problem? Is there a way that can run the Retrain without docker? And, if both the problems are difficult to solve, am I supposed to install a linux?

P.S. I'm using Win10, python version is 3.5 which is installed using Anaconda and coding in VS2015, tensorflow version is gpu-0.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a more complete set of instructions in "[TensorFlow For Poets - Setting up](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#1)" (for Linux and Mac)

On Windows, make sure your [Docker Toolbox (the one using Boot2docker)](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) is properly setup.
Make sure, on Windows 10, that you don't have the [Hyper-V Windows already activated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v#manually-enable-the-hyper-v-role), as both Hyper-V and VirtualBox have some issues running together.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! I didn't install the Docker Toolbox at all, only installed a docker-install, because I don't know that Docker Toolbox is needed: no tutorials have ever mentioned that. Now I can run tensorflow retrain properly!